# Clang or GCC compiler for c++ 11 compatibility programming on Windows?

Tags: windows, c++11, gcc, clang, compatibility

I was wondering which compiler is better to use  on Windows OS (8.1) in temrs of compatibility to c++11's (and later 14) functions, liberies and features (like lambdas) and is also comfortable to use (less bugs).

I am a university student hence I'm not looking at the subject product-wise (even though I do like to code a bit more than just projects for my studies).

I am currently using eclipse luna IDE if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `compiler != IDE`.

VC++ is one of the most populars on Windows and [depending on its version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/21/c-11-14-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp3.aspx) it has a good support for C++11 features. Check the list on the msdn blog to find out if there's everything you need.

Gcc is also ported to Windows and you can install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to use it (4.8.1.4 at the moment of writing this). It is [pretty complete](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) on C++11.

Clang is also available for the Windows platform and it is also [complete](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) on C++11 support (plus it has good diagnostic messages), but notice that you will have to use another linker since clang doesn't ship with one (although there is an ongoing effort to write it: http://lld.llvm.org/)

All the compilers I cited above are pretty stable but, based on my experience, if you're looking for latest and greatest C++11/14/17 features, you might just want to go for gcc or clang (VC++ is slower in adding support for newest features and the compiler is undergoing a huge update to modernize). Just keep in mind that these are *compilers* and not just *IDEs*, an IDE is a front-end supporting program that uses a compiler undercover to compile files.

Comment: I know the difference between an IDE and a compiler, I was simply wondering if there is a comfortable and recommanded IDE for c++11 AND on a different note, a good compiler. I'm currently using Eclipse Luna with mingw 4.9.2 and was simply wondering if there is a better alternative for me (since Clang supports more options and Ecplise is lacking in few features compared to other IDEs)

Comment: So my question is basically is there a better combination than Eclipse Luna IDE + GCC MinGW 4.9.2 compiler for c++11 programming on Windows??

Comment: For the compilers I already listed the differences in the post above. As IDE it's a matter of personal taste. Some people even prefer to use a personalized vim or sublime text in a Windows environment so it really is a subjective answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a C++11 compiler, I suggest installing [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/), it has a package manager (pacman) that can install fresh versions of GCC, GDB, Clang and many libraries like SDL, Lua etc. Very easy to use too.

As far as GCC vs CLang goes - I really tried hard to make CLang work (which is presumably faster and more friendly than GCC - produces better warnings, etc.), but failed. Issues were that CLang (which comes with MSYS2) is hard-coded to use GCC linker which produces some strange linker errors when using libstdc++ (std implementation from GCC). libc++ (a new implementation designed to work with CLang) didn't worked for me on Windows either.
So you either try build CLang from sources and hope that some configuration will work with C++11 library, OR just stick with **GCC** which works just fine out of the box.

As IDE, I suggest to take a look at [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). It is very comfortable (infinitely more user-friendly and intuitive than Visual Studio, IMO). Just install it and point it to the mingw64 (or mingw32) folder of MSYS2, it will auto-detect everything for you.

It only works with CMake projects though.